# OKTA express middleware - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, okta

Just including the following in an app causes the following error.

```
const { ExpressOIDC } = require('@okta/oidc-middleware');
```

Full error:

```
$ node app.js 
internal/util.js:257
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('original', 'Function', original);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
    at promisify (internal/util.js:257:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dev/tmpOidc/node_modules/jose/lib/jwk/key/rsa.js:13:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dev/tmpOidc/node_modules/jose/lib/jwk/import.js:9:16)
```

Steps to reproduce
1. Create a new node app and add express and Okta's oidc [middleware](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-web-app/nodeexpress/before-you-begin/)

```
npm init
npm install express --save
npm install --save @okta/oidc-middleware
```

2. Create app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// const { ExpressOIDC } = require('@okta/oidc-middleware');

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

3. Run it

```
node app.js
```

See how it runs.  Finally, uncomment and include the line that sets up the OIDC middleware.

```
const { ExpressOIDC } = require('@okta/oidc-middleware');
```

Run the app again and I get the error above shows up.

**Solved:  Need to run with node v12 not v10**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just published a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgpsNi_6mzg) that shows you how to use Okta's OIDC Middleware.

You can find the steps I used [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/06/16/nodejs-login#create-an-express-app-and-add-login-in-5-steps). To summarize:

1. Create a new project with express-generator and pug: `npx express-generator --view=pug`
2. Add a new **web** app on Okta with `http://localhost:3000/callback` as the login redirect URI
3. Install Schematics CLI: `npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli`
4. Install and run OktaDev Schematics with your Okta values:

```
npm i @oktadev/schematics
schematics @oktadev/schematics:add-auth --issuer=$issuer --clientId=$clientId -- 
clientSecret=$clientSecret
```

5. Start your app and authenticate with Okta: `npm start`

You can see the result of these steps in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-nodejs-login-example).

Comment: Nice work Matt. This will help folks get started with okta.  My problem though was a node version issue and not a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. When I posted my question I should've included system information such as the version of Node. I had v10.8.0.  Once I updated to v12 the typeerror went away.